# Sharepoint Calculated Formula to List Field

Tags: sharepoint

I have this formula but it shows syntax error. Can anyone help me? It has three conditionals.

```
A B C
If (A - (B + C) > 0) "OK"
If (A - (B + C) <= 0) "Open"
IF (A <= C) "Closed"

=IF([A]-([B]+[C])>0;"Ok";"Open";IF([A] <= [C]);"Closed"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have syntax error in the formula.

Refer below formula. This will work for you.

```
=IF(A<=C,"Closed",IF(A-(B+C)<=0,"Open",IF(A-(B+C)>0,"Ok")))
```